# Word search algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to come up with a better approach than the "brute force" method, but am at somewhat of a loss.

Here is a simple case:

Given a finite number of pre-chosen letters, and a hatch (like a crossword overlap) I am attempting to find all combination of words that can be used. (Words are retrieved from a dictionary database.)

Example:

Given the letters:
 
a,c,r,e,t,u,p,l,m,o
how many combinations of words can fit in the following crossword puzzle?

```
   _
 _ _ _ _ 
   _
   _
   _ _ _
```

One example:

```
  c
t r e e
  e
  e
  p o t
```

Of course the search time increases dramatically with each letter or addition to the crossword hatch. Any suggestions for a better way to search?

Comment: I can reduce a dictionary of 62 000 words with `sed 's|/.*||' /var/cache/postgresql/dicts/en_us.dict | egrep "^[acretuplmo]{3,5}$" | wc ` to 566 words in a first, rough cut. But I'm curious: you're using 4 times `e`, but no `a` at all. Is this alright?

Comment: yes, the words are created using any of the letters provided (and each letter can be used multiple times)

Answer (score 4):

Check out the open source [arccc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/arccc/), which fills in crossword grids by treating them as a [constraint satisfaction problem](http://www.cis.temple.edu/~ingargio/cis587/readings/constraints.html). If you would like to do this yourself as a learning exercise, reading up on CSPs should be a good starting point.

As for limiting the alphabet, that's best done as a preprocessing step on the source dictionary.